# Send information from computer to Arduino via USB (basic clock)

Tags: serial, usb, time

I've created a small project using an Uno. I usually mess around with ESP8266 chips, because they have WiFi and are relatively easy to work with. However, this time I've decided to go right back to the Uno.

I've made a clock using a bunch of MAX7219 matrix displays (32x8 total). I want to be able to sync the time from the computer to the Arduino, no matter which PC is connected.

My thought was to create a small program, that detects the connected Uno, then sends the data over serial. However, there's probably a more clever way to do that, which requires very little programming on the PC side.

Any clues? The Arduino is connected via USB. Would love this to work on both Windows and MacOS.

Comment: no, there is no other way

Comment: you might find a terminal app that can echo the current time, but it's a one-line program anyway...

Comment: in windows, you could write a batch file